# How can I modify the value of one dropdown based on a selection in another?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm using AG-Grid Community with full-row editing in a grid. I have 2 fields that use agSelectCellEditor. I'm wondering if it's possible to capture a change to the first field during the editing process and, based on the selected value, modify the value of the second field. Looking through the available events/functions, I can't find something that works. If this was based on standard HTML form controls, the JS would look something like:

```
const selectOne = document.getElementById("field-a-select");
const selectTwo = document.getElementById("field-b-select");
selectOne.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (selectOne.value === 'a certain value') {
        selectTwo.value = 'a default value that the user might change';
    }
});
```

Is there a way to add a change event listener to an agSelectCellEditor and, on change, get the selected value and use it to modify the selected value in another agSelectCellEditor?

I tried capturing the first value via rowValueChanged and cellValueChanged but these are only fired when the editing stops as opposed to during. I also can't find anything in the docs about attaching specific events to the agSelectCellEditor to detect changes during the editing process. I do have existing code for getting all the cellEditors and can identify the editor for the second field, but can't find anything for actually setting the value of the agSelectCellEditor and having the drop-down label updated with the new selection. If I can capture the change to the first select, I can probably figure out how to update the second, but I'm hesitant to do so if there's a good standard way for changing the value of an agSelectCellEditor while it's actively shown.

EDIT: I've added an example:

EXPIRED LINK REMOVED

What I'm trying to accomplish is to capture a change *during the full-row edit* in the "Make" field and automatically update the selected value of "Model" to "Unknown" before the row is saved. The cell edit events I'm familiar with in AG-GRID only fire after the full row edit here is saved.

EDIT 2: I did find a "solution" here, though it's well outside the documentation of AG Grid and definitely may not be a great long term approach. It did work for me on AG Grid 31. Sample config below -- the important part is in the "onRowEditingStarted" function.

```
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    {
      field: "make",
      cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: ["Porsche", "Toyota", "Ford", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"],
      },
    },
    {
      field: "model",
      cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: ["Unknown", "ModelA", "ModelB", "ModelC", "ModelD", "ModelE"],
      },
    },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true,
    cellDataType: false,
  },
  editType: "fullRow",
  rowData: getRowData(), // whatever gets your data
  onRowEditingStarted: () => {
    const influencingColumnField = "make";
    let influencingColumnIndex = null;
    const influencedColumnField = "model";
    let influencedColumnFieldIndex = null;
    const cols = gridApi.getEditingCells();
    for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
      if (cols[i].column.colId === influencingColumnField) {
        influencingColumnIndex = i;
      } else if (cols[i].column.colId === influencedColumnField) {
        influencedColumnFieldIndex = i;
      }
    }
    if (
      influencingColumnIndex !== null &&
      influencedColumnFieldIndex !== null
    ) {
      const editors = gridApi.getCellEditorInstances();
      const selectA = editors[influencingColumnIndex];
      const selectB = editors[influencedColumnFieldIndex];
      selectA.eSelect.addEventListener("fieldValueChanged", (e) => {
        selectB.eSelect.setValue("Unknown");

      });
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Comment: One example people use is to change the county dropdown based on the state dropdown .... So perhaps you could Google that and see if anything comes up.

Comment: Could you please try and recreate your issue in StackBlitz or similar (it's best to adjust a working example from the ag-grid website to save you time).  That gives us something to play with

Answer (score 1):

Since you added javascript thought of providing an answer. The below code will generate a drop-down two items based on the selection of drop-down one using the change event. You can enhance this accordingly to adopt to your use case.

```js
    const firstDropdown = document.getElementById('firstDropdown');
    const secondDropdown = document.getElementById('secondDropdown');

    const optionsBySelection = {
      option1: ['Suboption 1.1', 'Suboption 1.2', 'Suboption 1.3'],
      option2: ['Suboption 2.1', 'Suboption 2.2', 'Suboption 2.3'],
      option3: ['Suboption 3.1', 'Suboption 3.2', 'Suboption 3.3'],
    };

    
    firstDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {    
      secondDropdown.innerHTML = ''; 
      const selectedValue = firstDropdown.value;
      optionsBySelection[selectedValue].forEach(function(option) {
        const optionElement = document.createElement('option');
        optionElement.value = option;
        optionElement.textContent = option;
        secondDropdown.appendChild(optionElement);
      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dropdown Interaction</title>
</head>
<body>

  <label for="firstDropdown">Select Option 1:</label>
  <select id="firstDropdown">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  </select>

  <label for="secondDropdown">Select Option 2:</label>
  <select id="secondDropdown">
  </select>


</body>
</html>
```